# Task :google_maps_flutter:testDebugUnitTest FAILED

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, flutter-test

I have this error that I cannot seem to solve. I have searched everywhere, but no answers.
Here below you'll see a detailed description of the problem:

```
> Task :google_maps_flutter:testDebugUnitTest

    io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.CircleBuilderTest > density_AppliesToStrokeWidth PASSED
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended

    io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.CircleControllerTest > controller_SetsStrokeDensity FAILED
    org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException at CircleControllerTest.java:20
        Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException at CircleControllerTest.java:20                                                                      
            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException at CircleControllerTest.java:20                                                                               
                Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at CircleControllerTest.java:20    

    io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.GoogleMapControllerTest > OnDestroyReleaseTheMap STANDARD_OUT                                                                          
    Downloading from maven

    io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.GoogleMapControllerTest > OnDestroyReleaseTheMap FAILED
    java.lang.RuntimeException at ReflectionHelpers.java:223                                                                                                         
        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException at ReflectionHelpers.java:208                                                                                          
            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException at FieldAccessorImpl.java:137

    io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.GoogleMapControllerTest > DisposeReleaseTheMap FAILED
    java.lang.RuntimeException at ReflectionHelpers.java:223
        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException at ReflectionHelpers.java:208
            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException at FieldAccessorImpl.java:137

    io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.GoogleMapControllerTest > MethodCalledAfterControllerIsDestroyed FAILED
    java.lang.RuntimeException at ReflectionHelpers.java:223
        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException at ReflectionHelpers.java:208
            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException at FieldAccessorImpl.java:137

    io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.GoogleMapControllerTest > InvalidateMapAfterMethodCalls FAILED
    java.lang.RuntimeException at ReflectionHelpers.java:223
        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException at ReflectionHelpers.java:208
            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException at FieldAccessorImpl.java:137

    io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.GoogleMapControllerTest > InvalidateMapOnceAfterMethodCall FAILED
    java.lang.RuntimeException at ReflectionHelpers.java:223
        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException at ReflectionHelpers.java:208
            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException at FieldAccessorImpl.java:137

    io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.MarkersControllerTest > controller_OnMarkerDragStart FAILED
    org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException at MarkersControllerTest.java:32
        Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException at MarkersControllerTest.java:32
            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException at MarkersControllerTest.java:32
                Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at MarkersControllerTest.java:32


    io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.MarkersControllerTest > controller_OnMarkerDrag FAILED
    org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException at MarkersControllerTest.java:98
        Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException at MarkersControllerTest.java:98
            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException at MarkersControllerTest.java:98
                Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at MarkersControllerTest.java:98

    io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.MarkersControllerTest > controller_OnMarkerDragEnd FAILED
    org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException at MarkersControllerTest.java:65
        Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException at MarkersControllerTest.java:65
            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException at MarkersControllerTest.java:65
                Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at MarkersControllerTest.java:65

    
io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.PolygonBuilderTest > density_AppliesToStrokeWidth PASSED

    io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.PolygonControllerTest > controller_SetsStrokeDensity FAILED
    org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException at PolygonControllerTest.java:20
        Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException at PolygonControllerTest.java:20                                                                     
            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException at PolygonControllerTest.java:20
                Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at PolygonControllerTest.java:20

    io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.PolylineBuilderTest > density_AppliesToStrokeWidth PASSED

    io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.PolylineControllerTest > controller_SetsStrokeDensity FAILED
    org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException at PolylineControllerTest.java:20
        Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException at PolylineControllerTest.java:20
            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException at PolylineControllerTest.java:20
                Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at PolylineControllerTest.java:20

14 tests completed, 11 failed
```